# Custom scrolling always go back to top before scrolling

Tags: javascript, custom-scrolling

i tried to make a custom scrolling script that goes from one block to another in my website but when i click on my next button, the scrolling always jump to the top. I don't know why it always do that.

Here is my javascript code :

```
function myscroll(i)
{
    if (document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.body.scrollHeight - 50)
    {
        document.body.scrollTop += 1;
        if (document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight)
            setTimeout(function() { myscroll(i) }, 10);
    }
    else if (document.body.scrollTop < i - 100)
    {
        document.body.scrollTop += 10;
        if (document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight)
            setTimeout(function() { myscroll(i) }, 10);
    }
    else if (document.body.scrollTop < i - 50)
    {
        document.body.scrollTop += 5;
        if (document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight)
            setTimeout(function() { myscroll(i) }, 10);
    }
    else if (document.body.scrollTop < i)
    {
        document.body.scrollTop += 1;
        if (document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight)
            setTimeout(function() { myscroll(i) }, 10);
    }
}
```

here i made an exemple on jsbin : http://jsbin.com/ehIZAya/

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** Page jumping to top

The page jumps to the top because `href="#"` causes your browser to look for an element with ID of what comes after the `#`. For example:

- [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874578/custom-scrolling-always-go-back-to-top-before-scrolling/#20898954) is equivalent to `href="#20898954"` (since `20898954` is the ID of this answer); will cause your browser to jump to the top of this answer
- [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874578/custom-scrolling-always-go-back-to-top-before-scrolling/#) is equivalent to `href="#"`; it will cause your browser to jump to the top of the page

To fix this, you have two choices:

1. Remove each anchor's `href` attribute. Unfortunately, this method removes all styling (and it looks like ordinary text), which can be confusing. Instead, I prefer to...
2. Handle the click event itself in the `onclick` function with `preventDefault()`.

---

**Problem:** `document.body.scrollTop` always equals 0. In your code, the first `else if` executes as an infinite loop, since it is the first condition that evaluates to true. The problem is that you add pixels to `document.body.scrollTop`, which remains 0, and thus, the second condition always, in effect, calls itself to run again.

Replace `document.body.scrollTop` with `document.documentElement.scrollTop` for accurate readings of the current top of the viewable window, and to set it correctly.

---

To prevent the automatic jump to the top of the page, you can use `preventDefault()`. Assume each anchor has class `link`:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link")
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myscroll(someNumber);
    };
};
```

The problem there is `someNumber`. You could enter an integer value (i.e. `500`), and each link would scroll to the same place on the page (500px). You could enter an integer * i (i.e. `500 * i`), and each link would scroll to a multiple of 500px (0px, 500px, 1000px, etc.). But I chose to make this a little more customizable than that, with a custom attribute called `scroll-target`.

Each anchor is defined `<a class="link" href="#" scroll-target="500">`, where 500 might be any value. To get a custom attribute, use `element.getAttribute("attributeName")`. And so, we're left with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myscroll(this.getAttribute("scroll-target"));
    };
};
```

---

To apply this to your code, make sure each anchor is defined `<a class="link" href="#" scroll-target="500">`, replacing 500 with the actual value you want. You can also use a class name other than "link", but if you do, make sure you replace the class name in the second line of my script also.

On page load, it alerts a few values. Scroll to random places, and refresh the page. Take note which values change, and which remain the same. Do this a few times until you understand.

Javascript:

```
alert("document.body.scrollTop = " + document.body.scrollTop + "\ndocument.documentElement.scrollTop = " + document.documentElement.scrollTop + "\ndocument.body.scrollHeight = " + document.body.scrollHeight + "\nwindow.innerHeight = " + window.innerHeight);
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link")
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myscroll(this.getAttribute("scroll-target"));
    };
};

function myscroll(i) {
    // If bottom of currently viewable area is less than 50px from bottom of page
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.body.scrollHeight - 50) {
        console.log("1");
        document.documentElement.scrollTop += 1;
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight)
            setTimeout(function () {
                myscroll(i)
            }, 10);
    // If top of currently viewable area is 101px or more above target
    } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < i - 100) {
        console.log("2");
        document.documentElement.scrollTop += 10;
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight)
            setTimeout(function () {
                myscroll(i)
            }, 10);
    // If top of currently viewable area is 51-100px above target
    } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < i - 50) {
        console.log("3");
        document.documentElement.scrollTop += 5;
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight)
            setTimeout(function () {
                myscroll(i)
            }, 10);
    // If top of currently viewable area is 49px or less above target (including below target)
    } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < i) {
        console.log("4");
        document.documentElement.scrollTop += 1;
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight)
            setTimeout(function () {
                myscroll(i)
            }, 10);
    }
}
```

You might also want to add equal and opposite conditions for the top of the currently-viewable area being past/below the target, if you ever want to scroll upwards.